# Way of evaluating a line integral of a vector field without parameterization

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

Lets say we want to find the flux of some vector field over some surface $ f(x,y)$.

$\int \int_{S}^{} \overrightarrow{F}(x,y)*\overrightarrow{dA} $

What we do is we write $\overrightarrow{dA} = \overrightarrow{n}*dxdy$  where $\overrightarrow{n}$

is the normal vector of the surface at its every point.

$\overrightarrow{n} = (-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} , -\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},1)$

Then we performe dot product of the vector field $\overrightarrow{F}(x,y)$ with $ \overrightarrow{n} $ and in the end we end up with a double integral.

Now suppose we want to calculate the integral $\int_{C}^{}\overrightarrow{F}(x,y)*\overrightarrow{dl}$

is there a similar way to do this just like with the flux without need of parameterization of the curve $C$?

Comment: In the surface case, you're assuming $S$ is given as the graph of some function $f$. Wouldn't you consider that as "cheating" in some sense?

Comment: Why would it be cheating?

Comment: Like I said, you're already assuming $S$ is given to you as the graph of some function. Suppose I tell you to integrate over an elliptical surface: $S=\{(x,y,z)\,:\, (x/a)^2+(y/b)^2+(z/c)^2=1\}$; how would you proceed? This surface is not the graph of any function (only locally), so you can't directly use your approach to evaluating surface integrals here. So, at the end of the day, you need some information about what the surface is/ what the curve $C$ is. Then you can parametrize it appropriately to continue from there.